# After a while loop has finished, the code doesn't continue after that

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, runtime-error

I am trying to make a quiz, in python, where I use quite a few while loops, so I can easily leave code, or re run it. The problem is, once one of my nested loops has finished running, the code doesn't continue to run. I will leave some pseudocode incase my logic is incorrect, and the actual code after that.

```
Pseudocode
i = 0
array = [0]
while i < 1:
    while length of array < 11:
        do something
print "done something!"
```

Basically, once the length of array has reached 11, the print doesn't happen. 
Here is the actual code also

```
diff =int(input("Choose a difficulty; 1 2 3"))
diffs = [1, 2, 3]
while diff not in diffs:
    diff = int(input("Invalid input; choose a difficulty; 1 2 3"))
data = []#This will hold all of the data in the quiz file
answers = []#This will hold the current answers available to the user
answers2 = []#This will hold the current questions used, so that the answers do appear in a random order
letters = ["A. ","B. ","C. ","D. "]#This is so that each answer has an identifier
Questions = [0]
i = 0
score = 0
with open(filenameq,"r") as quizFile:
    fileReader = csv.reader(quizFile)
    for row in fileReader:
        data.append(row)#This creates a 2D array, so that the program can access specific values in the file
while i < 1:
    while len(Questions) < 11:
        a = 0
        while a in Questions:
            a = randint(0,9)
        Questions.append(a)
        print(data[0][a])#The cell where the question is located in the file
        answers = []
        answers2 = []
        for x in range(0,(diff+1)):
            answers.append(data[a+1][x])
        x = 0
        b = 0
        correct = 0 
        while x <= diff:
            b = randint(0,diff)
            if b in answers2:
                continue
            answers2.append(b)
            print(letters[x]+answers[b])
            if b == 0:#the first item in the CSV file is the correct value
                correct = x
            x += 1
        answer = input("Enter the letter of the answer you think is correct").upper()
        if correct == letters.index(str(answer[0]+". ")):#This is the index of the letter that the user entered, in the letters list
            score += 1
    print("Quiz finished")
    with open(filename,"a+") as scoreFile:
        fileWriter = csv.writer(scoreFile)
        fileReader = csv.reader(scoreFile)
        for row in fileReader:
            if row[0] == username:
                print(row)
                row[2] = "y"
                print(row)
                fileWriter.writerow(row)
```

Finally, here is the csv file i am trying to manipulate

```
What is the name of the gorgon in Greek Mythology?,How did a warrior defeat Medusa in Greek Mythology,Who is the God of the Yellow River in Chinese Mythology?,Who is the mother of Hephaestus in Greek Mythology?,Who is the mother of Hephaestus in Greek Mythology?,Which river was Achilles dipped in as a baby?,Where did Zeus cast the Titans after Cronus defeated them?,What does the Helm of Darkness grant to the wearer?,Which is a pantheon of Norse Gods - excluding the Aesir?,What is Yggdrasil?
Perseus,Medusa,Ares,Zeus
A Shield,A Virus,Laceration,Cavalry
He Bo,Yang Zing,Kukulkan Ah Puch
Hera,Aphrodite,Demeter,Persephone
Pomegranate,Orange,Guava,Apple
Styx,Cocytus,Acheron,Phlegethon
Tartarus,The Asphodel Meadows,The Underworld,The Mourning Fields
Invisibility,Invincibility,Immortality,Ignitability
Vanir,Hel,Tyr,Yggdrasil
A Plant,A Person,A Deity,A World
```

So, each question is at the top, and the possible answers are in the bottom for each question, with the correct answers as row[0], or the first index in each line.

Thank you in advance for helping me :)

EDIT: Added some extra code to my main code, that I forgot to include originally, to clarify what "diff" and "diffs" are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out myself, and it is exactly what I thought it was; the logic in the 1st nested while loop prevented it from ending, as the Questions array was `Questions = [0]`, and the `a` variable was prevented from being in `Questions` if `a` was already in `Questions`, but `a` could already be 0-9, when `0` was already in `Questions`. Basically, It never could end!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be due to the fact that you never close your initial while loop: `while i < 1`. Since the value of i stays at 0, your outermost while loop will never close, causing your program to be stuck in an infinite loop. If you close that loop by setting `i = 1` at the end, this particular problem should be resolved.

Comment: The code I wanted to be in, was already in the while i < 1 loop, but I fixed it, the 1st nested loop was the problem here, I accidently made it so that it can never end!